# Javascript, block current day and time based block day after

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a dotnet project.

the owner asked for a solution on their calendar where customers can chose date for pickup.

the case here is:

1. block previous dates.
2. block current day, customers shouldnt be able to pickup today.
3. Block tomorrow when clock hits 15.00 today and reset 00.00.

I had a solution that worked until recently, and I have no idea why it broke.

The last working solution:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() { //DISABLED PAST DATES IN APPOINTMENT DATE
  var dateToday = new Date();
  var month = dateToday.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = dateToday.getDate();
  var year = dateToday.getFullYear() ;

  if (month < 10)
    month = '0' + month.toString();
  if (day < 10)
    day = '0' + day.toString();
      day = day+1 
    var time = new Date().getTime();
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      if (time >= 15 && time <= d) {
    day = day+1;
  maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    } 
  var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

  $('#booking_depart_date').attr('min', maxDate);
});
```

The input code:

```
<div class="col-md-6"><label for="booking_depart_date">Hämtning</label><input type="date" id="booking_depart_date"  autocomplete="false" class="form-control" placeholder="åååå-mm-dd" value='<asp:Literal ID="litDateValueDepart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>' min='<asp:Literal ID="litMinDate" runat="server"/>' onchange='on_depart_date_change(event);' /><div class="error" id="error_booking_depart_date"></div></div>
```

At the moment I had to comment out some of the code to make sure previous dates are blocked, and added +1 to getdate() so current day is blocked. However the timebased block is still an issue to be solved.

Have tried different ways to log date and time. when I hit the if-statement and add a block the whole calendar resets to unblock everything.

Case 1 and 2 is at the moment solved but not 3.

Comment: `if (day < 10)
    day = '0' + day.toString();
      day = day+1` can you see an issue? ... if the day is say ... 1, then it becomes `"01"` ... then it becomes `"011"` ... and `vvvv` that too - complete disregard to date rules bro

Comment: `day = day+1; maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;` - this will also get you into trouble, if your `day` is already the last of the month to begin with. The `min` attribute accepts only _valid_ dates, but with this code you are likely to feed it something like `2023-01-32` or `2023-02-29` at some point.

Comment: @Yogi It was made with some javascript from before. the project is kinda old and outdated syntax. so i'm trying to sort it out in a fast way, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use Date methods to adjust time and date**

Date inputs expect dates to be valid and [in format yyyy-MM-dd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value). As others have commented, your code is prone to creating invalid dates by using simple addition.

A better solution is to use [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object methods to set the date forward by 1 or 2 days. This will automatically adjust the year and month to maintain a valid date. Additionally, if we use a UTC date then the built-in [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method can be used to generate the date strings in the correct format:

```
date.toISOString().substring(0, 10); 

// example: 2023-03-06T14:40:00.000Z --> 2023-03-06
```

The trick is to use the local date as though it were a UTC date without any time zone offset. And *voilà*, we can then use a date object to set the value, min, and max attributes of a date input.

[image]

**Bonus**

The date input can also accept a time by setting the type to [datetime-local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)

```
<input type="datetime-local">
```

And the same code will work with this by including the time part of the date string:

```
date.toISOString().substring(0, 19); // change from 10 to 19

// example: 2023-03-06T14:40:00.000Z --> 2023-03-06T14:40:00
```

**Snippet**

```js
// business hours
const CLOSE_HOUR = 15,
  depart = document.getElementById("booking_depart_date");

let date = new Date();

depart.value = depart.min = new Date(Date.UTC(
  date.getFullYear(),
  date.getMonth(),
  date.getDate() + (date.getHours() < CLOSE_HOUR ? 1 : 2)
)).toISOString().substring(0, 10);


// validation
function on_depart_date_change() {
  depart.reportValidity();
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: crimson;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row p-2">
<div class="col-6 col-md-6">
    <label for="booking_depart_date">Hämtning</label>
    <input type="date" id="booking_depart_date" autocomplete="false" class="form-control" placeholder="åååå-mm-dd" value='<asp:Literal ID="litDateValueDepart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>' min='<asp:Literal ID="litMinDate" runat="server"/>' 
    onchange='on_depart_date_change(event);'>
    <div class="error" id="error_booking_depart_date"></div>
</div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```